# ODBC could not complete the requested operation

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes

I am having a problem with an a lotus 8 agent running on a server.The agent tries to fetch data form a sybase database (using Sybase 11 ODBC driver).I can run the same agent from a cleint machine with no error, but when the agent runs on the server it ends with the following error. -> LS:DO- ODBC could not complete the requested operation.
If you have any ideas please forward it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that the odbc connection is setup properly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/29c762295e3ee5e68525699f0055e9e6?OpenDocument) post This might be related to a Bug. But in your case I'm pretty sure it's got something to deal with DSN (TCP/IP shared memory) misconfiguration.